# Setting e.handled = true in the MouseDoubleClick event in UserControl bubbles to Parent Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm

I have developed a WPF application following MVVM pattern.

**UserControl**

It has a textBox control and I have hooked up **MouseDoubleClick**.

```
 private void textbox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {                     
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

**Parent**

```
<ListView>
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding data}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

The problem is that even after setting e.Handled = true, DoubleClickCommand is called in the main view. I want DoubleClickCommand not to be fired when e.Handled = true.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You want to switch the click command on and off using the Handled property, is that it ?

Comment: Logically yes,  the MouseDoubleClick event is in UserControl and Parent as well. So on setting e.Handled = true in UserControl, the click command in parent control should not be called.

Comment: The MouseDoubleClick isn't fired from the same source, in the UC it's the TextBox, and on the Parent it's the ListViewItem!

Comment: Oh I got it, so is there any way to implement my requirement?

Comment: You could attach to the PreviewMouseDoubleClick event on the Child of the ListView that is setting e.Handled to true. This would prevent the event MouseDoubleClick event bubbling up to the parent I think.

Comment: Some explanation [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25cb2f03-2127-4c84-94fd-f6ef7c63bfa7/mousedoubleclick-event-does-not-bubble-according-to-snoop?forum=wpf)

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman, it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to use the same DoubleClickCommand at in both the parent and the usercontrol, let's say this is your usercontrol :

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp4.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" MouseDoubleClick="UserControl1_OnMouseDoubleClick">

<Grid>
   <TextBox Width="100" />
</Grid>
```

The Parent should look something like this:

```
<Window ... DataContext="{Binding ParentViewModel}" Name="Main">
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:UserControl1>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand,ElementName=Main}"
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding data}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </local:UserControl1>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Now the Handled property will work just fine.